# Fire on change event in each checkbox when its checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a simple quiz in which user can answer multiple questions by clicking next, now I want to change the checkbox background when the checkbox is checked

Here is a demo [quiz demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svd794rk/2/)

Here is what I have tried

A function to change the background color when checkbox is checked

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
      console.log('clicked');
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
        console.log('Chodzi')
          $(this).addClass("input-before"); 
      }
      else{
        console.log('Nie chodzi');
          $(this).removeClass("input-before");  
      } });
```

Now when I run my app and click the checkboxes, the checkboxes change the background, but when I click next and then click the checkboxes the background is not changing.

What do I need to change to get this working??

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox']").once(...` or `$("input[type='checkbox']").one(...`

Comment: @Eldar what does that suppose to do?  I want on each click the checkboxes it should change the background

Comment: @Eldar can you show us your solution if it's working on jsfiddle I haveprovided?

Comment: It seems that title mislead me. What you want is firing event handler just once?

Comment: @Eldar I want the on change event to fire on each click on checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is you are creating elements on the fly. But you code only attach event handlers to existing ones. What you need to is add event handler when you create new element so your code should be like this:

```
 function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        // here we add event handler for newly created checkboxes.
        nextQuestion.find("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
          console.log('clicked');
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            console.log('Chodzi')
            $(this).addClass("input-before");
          } else {
            console.log('Nie chodzi');
            $(this).removeClass("input-before");
          }
        });
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value=' + selections[questionCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if (questionCounter === 1) {
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if (questionCounter === 0) {

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      } else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne9rzjqp/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is easy, to add a listener to some dynamically added element you just have to use JQuery like this:

```
  $("section").on('change',"input[type='checkbox']", function(){
      console.log('clicked');
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
         console.log('Chodzi')
         $(this).addClass("input-before"); 
      }
      else {
         console.log('Nie chodzi');
         $(this).removeClass("input-before");  
      } 
  });
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnz5x8ea/1/) updated with my edit

So basically you have to add the listener to the container, it will "propagate" the listener to every `input[type='checkbox']` that is (or will be) its children.